# Manga where a Kid was cast out by his family and found dark book that helps him make friends

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, reincarnation

In the manga this kid (he was young) was cast out by his family and found this book where he could make people/his own monsters (the people he made could talk and have their own specialties) and he made some teammates like that and one of them was super smart. I think the story was a reincarnation story. It was all black and white and he found the book in, I think, a basement he was locked in or thrown into but I'm not sure. Also, him finding the book was predestined, I think.

Comment: Why was the kid cast out by his family? And where did he find the book? Also, was this story in full colour, or mostly black & white?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## "The Black Create Summoner: Revolt of Reincarnated"

Given your description, it might be "*[黒の創造召喚師―転生者の叛逆](https://anilist.co/manga/99774/Kuro-no-Souzou-Shoukanshi-Tenseisha-no-Hangyaku/)*" (in romaji, *Kuro no Souzou Shoukanshi: Tenseisha no Hangyaku*), most of the time translated as "**The Black Create Summoner: Revolt of Reincarnated**" or "*The Black Create Summoner: Revenge of the Reincarnated*".

I've put the synopsis down the answer for you to check.

### First volume cover

[image: 黑之创造召唤师―转生者的叛逆― cover]

### Synopsis

> Due to a god's mistake, high schooler Tsuguna died before his time. In exchange, the god agreed to do him a favor in his next life. Tsuguna is reborn to a noble household in a world with magic. He has an unusual form of magic that he requested from the god, the ability to create summoned creatures. However, his dark Japanese hair and eyes mark him as a cursed child in this new world, and his powers are slow to appear. He's kept in a dark basement where he reads his family's books, until one day he finally uncovers the key to his powers. Finally, he can set off into the world with his summoned companion to level up his skills!

Comment: As I'm new to Stack, feel free to point out anything I might need to do to enhance the quality of my answers.

Comment: It's by no means exclusive but there's a basic [answer guide for story id](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9444/how-to-write-a-good-story-id-answer?rq=1) and you may also find the [ask guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/58193) as well as the linked more specific ones useful to. There's also the [find guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12294/58193). However, this does look like quite a nice answer and you've hit most of the things to make a good answer!